# How to give a alert sound when someone connects to a listening port using netcat?

Tags: bash, networking, netcat

I want to give an alerting sound whenever someone connects to my port opened for listening, using netcat. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
while true
  netcat -l 1234 < /dev/null > /dev/null
  beep
done
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives an alert but disconnects the session as well.